# ImageView taking different size if made visible in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RecyclerView` which consist of few items in it. I have created a custom row for the item in the `RecyclerView`. In the `RecyclerView` some of the items will be locked and some will be open. I am showing lock image over the items which are locked while others which are open are having one `ImageView` and a `TextView`. But the size of lock items and open items are different.

**Below is the screenshot.**

[image]

Here is the custom row xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gameCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--Start Layout of the open items-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/customLevelLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/levelImage"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    tools:background="@drawable/white_circular_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/levelNameText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="45sp"
                    tools:text="1" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                tools:text="Tracing" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--End Layout of the open items-->

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/gameProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:padding="45dp" />

        <!--Lock image-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lockImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/lock_background"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**lock_background.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#88EAECED" />
            <size
                android:width="120dp"
                android:height="120dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/lock" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**white_background.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <size android:width="5dp"
        android:height="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

The lock image `visibility` is `GONE` in the layout. I am changing its `Visibility` through code.

Comment: Are you sure the size of the lock image and the size of the open image are the same ? If yes, you should check the content(the orange circle in the open image and white circle in lock image) of both images are the same size also? If you don't understand my mean, could you post two images here ? I will check for you

Comment: @LQGioan the lock image has `match_parent` as height and width and the orange image has `120dp` as height and width.

Comment: Could you show me `lock_background and white_circular_background` drawable ?

Comment: updated the question with the layouts @LQGioan

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I moved the lock image on the first item of the `FrameLayout`. I saw that the open image and the lock image are not the same size.

**To fixed it -> try the below code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gameCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--Start Layout of the open items-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/customLevelLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/levelImage"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    tools:background="@drawable/white_circular_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/levelNameText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="45sp"
                    tools:text="1" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                tools:text="Tracing" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--End Layout of the open items-->

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/gameProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:padding="45dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!--Lock image-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lockImage"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lock_background"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**lock_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

**white_circular_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Try copy my code, I have modified somethings. Just change drawable.

Comment: I think you did something wrong. I have updated my answer. Could you try again. **Remember: try to copy all my code for testing first.**

Comment: Let me check again.

Comment: In the xml editer, you should change `android:visibility` of the `lockImage` `ImageView` from `visible` to `gone` and from `gone` to `visible` you will see the result. I'm not sure you did the right things in your java code or not.

Comment: I have posted the answer which worked out for me at last. Check it.

Comment: @Hirent: :)))))

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question with the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gameCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--Start Layout of the open items-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/customLevelLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/levelImage"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    tools:background="@drawable/white_circular_background" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/levelNameText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="45sp"
                    tools:text="1" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gameText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                tools:text="Tracing" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--End Layout of the open items-->

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/gameProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:padding="45dp" />

        <!--Lock image-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lockImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/lock_background"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000"
                tools:text="Tracing" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

it worked out at last.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your Lock images dimensions are

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

When levelImage is `120dp`

Comment: Even I feel the same. But the problem is the TextView below the `ImageView`.

Comment: Okey then 'levelNameText' must be outer in that layout you change visibility

Comment: Yes its outside the layout which is containing the orange image. @mbakgun

Answer (score 0):

You may try to replace the `ImageView` with below code this:-

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lockImage"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:gravity="CenterInParent"
    tools:background="@drawable/lock_background">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/lock"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**lock_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#88EAECED"/>
        <size android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: `120dp` is just the size of the `ImageView` but there is a TextView also under the image which is increasing the height of the Orange image layout.

Comment: I don't think soo that Textview increase the size of ImageView Size

Comment: It increases the layout height. `120dp` is the size of the `ImageView` and there is a `TextView` below it. Please check my question.

Comment: You are talking about levelNameText textview?

Comment: I Think, you should try once my code because your textview have lots of space inside ImageView and You dIdn't set any padding or margin in Textview.